# Are there non-trivial automorphisms of stable framed quiver representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers

Let $Q=(Q_0,Q_1)$ be a quiver and $q\in Q_0$ a chosen vertex. Let $d$ be a dimension vector with $d_q=1$ and let $\theta\in \mathbb R^{Q_0}$ be a $d$-generic stability parameter. Let $M$ be a $\theta$-stable $Q$-representation of dimension $d$. Let $f$ be an automorphism of $M$ which is the identity on the component $M_q$. Is it true that $f$ must necessarily be the identity of $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All automorphisms of the quiver representation you mention are by multiplication by scalars.  So as $f$ is the identity on $M_q$ it must be the identity on $M$.

Under your assumptions, $g=f-\mathrm{Id}_M$ is an endomorphism of $M$ with nonzero kernel.  The morphism $g\colon M\rightarrow \mathrm{Im}(g)$ is surjective, and so if $\mathrm{Im}(g)\neq 0$ the slope of this representation is at least as great as that of $M$, by stability.  On the other hand, $\mathrm{Im}(g)$ is a submodule of $M$, so its slope is no greater than that of $M$.  Putting these two inequalities together we get that $\mathrm{Im}(g)$ is either zero, or has the same slope as $M$.

Under the genericity assumptions, $M$ cannot have a subrepresentation of the same slope, since the dimension vector of such a subrepresentation would have to divide $d$, and $d_q=1$.  So $\mathrm{Im}(g)=0$ and $f=\mathrm{Id}_M$.